# Converting multiple duplicate rows into columns R

Tags: r, duplicates

I am new to R and I have a data frame with multiple duplicates in the first column, however the second column has unique values.

I want to keep the unique values in the first column and have a different column for each unique value.

My current data frame looks something like this:

```
Item    Value
Apricot 4
Apricot 2
Apricot 5
Banana  4
Carrot  7
Carrot  5
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
Item    Value 1     Value 2     Value 3
Apricot     4           2           5
Banana      4       
Carrot      7           5
```

Thanks in advance.
Fojjit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be easily done with `data.table` (if you are using the `devel` version i.e. `1.9.7`, installation details [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)).  The convenient function `rowid` can get the sequence based on a variable.  Use this in the `dcast` formula and we get the 'wide' output.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), Item~rowid(Item, prefix="Value"), value.var="Value")
#      Item Value1 Value2 Value3
#1: Apricot      4      2      5
#2:  Banana      4     NA     NA
#3:  Carrot      7      5     NA
```

Comment: I am struggling to use the function rowid, could you help? thanks

Comment: @Fojjit. The `rowid` function is not available in `data.table` 1.9.6, the version available for download on CRAN. To use `rowid`, you would have to download the development version, 1.9.7 as is outlined in the link in the answer.

Comment: @akrun Though this is a old one, it helped me for one of my analysis. However, would be great if you could tell when one more variable get added in df1 which needs to be casted. i.e., Item, value, Amount.

Comment: @ssan Please post as a new question

Answer (score 3):

You need an extra column for the value order. Them you can use `spread`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
your.data %>%
  group_by(Item) %>%
  mutate(Order = seq_along(Item)) %>%
  spread(key = Order, value = Value)
```

Comment: What do you mean by add a column for the value order? thanks